# For a regular polygon with n edges, Is $z_k^n=1$?

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

Question:
Given is a regular polygon with n edges, which has a corner point located on the
positive real axis. Show that for all n corner points is valid $z_k$ gilt: $z_k^n=1$

Above is an assignment question(for polar coordinate system), I do not know what is the exact meaning conveyed here since some German math term is used. please help understand and solve.

EDIT:

From this,
General form,
Since a vertice lies in positive real axis,
$$  z_k = r_ke^{iθ_k}, k= 0, 1, ...(n-1);\\ 
\begin{align} 
& => r_k[cos(k.2π)+isin(k.2π)] \\
& = r_k\\
\end{align}
$$
How to say this is true for a regular polygon without unity r and not lying in center ?, Is it possible ?

Comment: The vertexes of the polygon are the $n$th roots of the unity.

Answer (score 1):

Embed a regular polygon with $n$ edges in the complex plane (with one vertex on the $x$-axis, i.e. $1$) and denote it's vertices by $z_1, \dots, z_n$, then show for every $1\leq k\leq n$ that $z_k^n=1$.

For example, for the triangle we have that the corners lie on the three points $1$ and $-\frac{1}{2}\pm i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. This all relates to a concept in complex analysis called the "roots of unity", as you will show through your work on this problem that the vertices of these polygons are the roots of the equation $x^n=1$.

**Regarding the edit:**

In general, if you wish to center the polygon at $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$, have radius $r$, and have the root that is normally at $\alpha+1$ rotated by $\theta$ radians about $\alpha$, you would be considering the roots of

$$(x-\alpha)^n=r^ne^{i\theta}.$$

Comment: But it doesn't mean center of the polygon must lie in the polar coordinate origin ?, am I right ?

Comment: @SubhasshMahenthren The center of the polygon will also be at the origin. It is possible to fix a vertex at $1+0i$ and the center at $0+0i$.

Comment: Is it possible to generalize without fixing the center to origin ?

Comment: @SubhasshMahenthren See my edit.

Comment: @SubhasshMahenthren If you feel like I've sufficiently answeres your question, please mark it with a check mark :)

Comment: I still feel the question is unclear, where does the question say the radius is 1 for the corner point ?, the corner point can lie at any r distance on positive real axis of the polar coordinate. so that brings to the LHS of given eqn as $r_k^n$, which is clearly not 1. so how should I do the proof for $z_k^n=1$ ?

Comment: @SubhasshMahenthren The question provides that one corner is on the real axis and every corner point $z_k$ satisfies $z_k^n=1$. Hence one corner point lies on $1$, since it is the only real number that satisfies the equation. I described in yhe first sentence of my answer how to proceed with the proof -- but as this is an assignment question I am inclined to not provide you with a full solution.